# How to start named Agent through Supervisor.init?

Tags: elixir

I have a very simple mix app (which is a part of the phoenix umbrella project). It even doesn't include processes for business logic. For example:

```
defmodule BGAdapter.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      BGAdapter.LifeCycle # Agent
    ]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one, name: BGAdapter.Supervisor)
  end
end
```

My `Agent` called twice. Once `put`, second `get`.
So I want to replace separate `Agent` `BGAdapter.LifeCycle` module with smth like:

```
defmodule BGAdapter.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      { Agent, fn -> %{} end, name: BGAdapter.LifeCycle } # This does not work
    ]
...
```

The error is:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application bg_adapter: exited in: BGAdapter.Application.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (ArgumentError) supervisors expect each child to be one of the following:

  * a module
  * a {module, arg} tuple
  * a child specification as a map with at least the :id and :start fields
  * or a tuple with 6 elements generated by Supervisor.Spec (deprecated)

Got: {Agent, #Function<0.33439399/0 in BGAdapter.Application.start/2>, [name: BGAdapter.LifeCycle]}
```

How can I start `Agent` "inline"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hauleth which answered it in Elixir-lang slack.

The correct line would be:

```
%{id: BGAdapter.LifeCycle, start: {Agent, :start_link, [fn -> %{} end, [name: BGAdapter.LifeCycle]]}}
```

Application file:

```
defmodule BGAdapter.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      %{
        id: BGAdapter.LifeCycle,
        start: {Agent, :start_link, [fn -> %{} end, [name: BGAdapter.LifeCycle]]}
      }
    ]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one, name: BGAdapter.Supervisor)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure, but I think the problem is that `Agent` has its own `start` (and `start_link`) format. It does not receive implementation. I mean - `GenServer.start(Impl, init_args, opts)` vs `Agent.start(init_fn, opts)`